# Insert a space in a string containing alphanumeric characters at the beginning and end of each number in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string similar to `98abcd123fgh324ijklm564asd`. I want to insert a couple of spaces before and after each number in the string. Below is the sample output:

```
str = "98abcd123fgh324ijklm564asd"

required_function(str)
# " 98 abcd 123 fgh 324 ijklm 564 asd"
```

Comment: That sounds like a task for us, what have you tried and what problem you have with that code/regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I dont understand regexes very well. Instead, I created two columns. Column1 with all the alphabets replacing the digits with space and Column2 with all the numbers, replacing the alphabets with space. That suffices the requirement. I was thinking if this could be done with regex in more efficient way.

Comment: You see, it is *basic* regex: `gsub("(\\d+)", " \\1 ", str)`. Really, I think you need to read [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "98abcd123fgh324ijklm564asd"
gsub("(\\d+)", " \\1 ", str)
```

Comment: Come on. That is too basic. No wonder I cannot find another question like this on SO to close the question with.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree but that's an answer though

Comment: @rock321987 thanks a ton..